# Error in comparing images of diffrerent dimension using ssim

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, scikit-image, ssim

Below is the code for comparing two images I am using:

```
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments


# load the two input images
imageA = cv2.imread('iron1.jpg')
imageB = cv2.imread('end.jpg')
(H, W, C) = imageA.shape
imageB = cv2.resize(imageB, imageA.shape)
# convert the images to grayscale
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
```

and Getting below error for resize of two images:

```
  File "C:/Users/afaraz/PycharmProjects/tet/opencv_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    imageB=cv2.resize(imageB, imageA.shape)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Please help on this issue!!

Comment: shape has 3 arguments for a color image. So imageA.shape has 3 arguments. But resize only wants (w,h), not (w,h,c). So you need imageA.shape[:2] so that it returns only (w,h) and not (w,h,c)

Comment: Still getting same error:

Comment: shape gives (h,w,c).  resize needs (w,h). So the two arguments need to be swapped.